# pthread library undefined reference

Tags: c

I'm using eclipse on Fedora 17 (with GCC) and I have an undefined reference on pthread_create (), even if pthread.h is included and if I have -lpthread on the gcc build command line...

Here is my code, just in case

```
void* repair()
{
    int var;
    for ( var = 0; var < NB_ITER ; var += 2 )
    {
        printf( "PAIR : %d\n", var );
    }

return NULL;
} // pair

void exo03()
{
    pthread_t id1;
    pthread_create(&id1, NULL, &repair, NULL);
}
```

Thank you for helping :)

Comment: You probably forgot you to link with pthread library. Add `-lpthread` in your compile command as the last one.

Comment: Can you provide a full example and exact note of compiler command + errors please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On linux, FreeBSD (and some other *nix flavors) you should use the compiler option `-pthread` and not trying to link with a pthread library.

For [eclipse](http://blog.asteriosk.gr/2009/02/15/adding-pthread-to-eclipse-for-using-posix-threads/) :

> Eclipse is not configured to put the -pthread argument in the gcc
> compilation. To solve this, go to the Menu:
>
> Project -> Properties
>
> c/c++ build -> GCC C Compiler -> Miscellaneous
>
> Add the “-pthread” argument into the beginning of the “Other Flags”
>
> Also go to:
>
> c/c++ build -> Settings -> GCC C Linker -> Libraries
>
> And include the “pthread”library into the other libraries. Click Apply and rebuild
> the project. Pthreads must work now.

From [man gcc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc):

> -pthread : Adds support for multithreading with the pthreads library. This option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker.

I found an [explanation here](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/difference-between-lpthread-pthread-compilation-opts-help-200784191.html#200784201) :

> In GCC, the **-pthread** (aka -pthreads) option manages both the compiler
> preprocessor /and/ linker to enable compilation with Posix threads.
> The preprocessor will define/enable/use Posix threads versions of some
> macros (or perform conditional compilation to enable Posix threads
> logic), and the linker will specifically link the resultant object
> against libpthread
>
> However, **-lpthread** simply tells the linker to attempt to resolve any
> external references against the libpthread library, in the same way
> that -lm tells the linker to attempt to resolve any external
> references against the libm library. For -lpthread, your code might
> not contain external references to libpthread, even if you wrote Posix
> thread code, because the critical macros haven't been switched on.

Comment: Why not link against libpthread?

Comment: @bash.d : because without the `-pthread` option, compîler and linker will fail to find the correct pthread library :)

Comment: Is it important to write the lpthread option first ? Because right now, I have this : gcc .... -O0 -g3 -Wall -lpthread -c -fmessage-length=0 (Eclipse settings, I just added -lpthread)

Comment: @Hahuha : I added in my answer the way of doing this in eclipse

Comment: Hoo thank's ! Now I can build ! Doesn't work, but I can build it n_n

Answer (score 6):

Have you linked to libpthread?

```
$> gcc ... -lpthread
```